# Push notifications to two apps by different developers

Tags: android, ios, push-notification, push

Company A is developing an app which it releases to it users and can send push notifications to them

Company A has also has an open API because its service is so amazing and other companies want to develop there own apps to talk to its data.

So company B comes along as builds its own app thats uses company A's API

Is it possible that when company B talks to company A's API, part of the handshake is company A storing the push notification identifier of company's B app.

So that in the future company A can send a push notification to users who use its own app offering but also users who have chosen to use company's B app to access company A's data.

Can you send a push to another developers app if you know its push identifier?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To be a push notification provider for **iOS** you will need:

1. Establish secured connection with APNS (Apple push notification service) ,this can be done by two ways:

   - Certificate based - you will need the **Private key** of the app's push certificate which issued on the developer portal.
   - Token based - you will need a **Private key** from the developer to generate JWT (JSON web token) to connect to APNS.
2. Know where to send the push to, this is done by a device token (which contains the specific device and app) which the app needs to send to the provider.

So if you want that Company A will be able to send push to Company A and Company B it will need:

- Company A app to send device token to **Company A server**.
- Company A private key and push certificate to be stored on **Company A server**.
- Company B app to send device token to **Company A server**.
- Company B private key and push certificate to be stored on **Company A server**.

Hope it helps.